# Why might my RoR Ambethia Recaptcha plugin/gem be returning only false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I'm trying to set up Recaptcha in my Ruby-on-Rails app (Rails 3), using [Ambethia's plugin or gem](http://ambethia.com/recaptcha/). After I install the plugin or gem and set up my public and private keys in a config/initializers/recaptcha.rb, I use it like this:

## show view where my form is displayed

```
<%=raw recaptcha_tags %>
```

## controller where I need to check the recaptcha

```
if verify_recaptcha && @question.save
...
else
  flash[:error] = "Incorrect word verification. Are you sure you're human?"
  redirect_to :back
end
```

No matter what, 'verify_recaptcha' returns false and so the form posting doesn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

check out this Rails 3 example:

```
https://github.com/tilo/mail_form_example_with_recaptcha
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer for my problem. I got wrong recaptcha because of timeout. In verify.rb there is a block where posting to API is proceeding, and it is depending on timeout, that can be set in params of verify() call. And I think that my inet is too slow that's why 3 wasn't enough. I called verify(:timeout => 50) and it worked perfectly.